# Customizing GFM markdown output in Pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext

I am trying to convert some .rst files to .md (GitHub flavoured markdown) using Pandoc.

I want to use `#` and `##` instead of `===` and `---` for headers and subheaders. I also want code samples to be in simple code fences and not with block quotes.

If I have the .rst sample on the left in a file called `rst.rst`, I get the markdown on the right by running `pandoc rst.rst -t gfm` - it uses the 'wrong' header style and adds a blockquote to the code sample.

How can I fix this? Do I need to write a custom lua filter?

[image: markdown and rst comparison]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force ATX style headers, use the `--markdown-headings=atx` [commandline option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--markdown-headings).

```
pandoc rst.rst -t gfm --markdown-headings=atx
```

To avoid the blockquote, remove the indentation from your rst code block. Note that a [blockquote](https://restructuredtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rst_guide.html#blockquotes) is represented by indenting a block of text in RestructuredText. Therefore, your code block is nested within a blockquote in your rst document and Pandoc is correctly replicating that document structure in the Markdown output.

````sh
$ echo "
> Header
> ======
>
> some text
>
> Subheader
> ---------
>
> A code sample
>
> .. sourcecode:: python3
>     :linenos:
>
>     class Hand(Deck):
>         pass
>
> More text" | pandoc -f rst -t gfm --markdown-headings=atx
# Header

some text

## Subheader

A code sample

``` python3
class Hand(Deck):
    pass
```

More text
````

Note that I get the same result without specifying the `--markdown-headings` option, which makes sense because `ATX` is documented to be the default. Perhaps you are using an older version of Pandoc, in which case you may need to use the now-deprecated `--atx-headers` instead. I used Pandoc version 2.11.4 to generate the example above.

Comment: Thanks for the information - super helpful! I was using the same version, but I had to add the `-f rst` - I thought pandoc would pick that up automatically from the `.rst` extension.